Do we redevelop a building or do we only redevelop an area?

redevelop: the act or process of changing an area by building new roads, houses, factories, etc.

It seems that we only redevelop an area, but dictionary definitions aren't always correct, so I wonder if we can say:

There used to be a gift shop here, but it was then redeveloped into a travel agent.


Your gift shop sentence would not be idiomatic.  If the gift shop had  been demolished as part of a larger redevelopment project you could say,  perhaps with some sarcasm in your voice, "... but it was redeveloped into a parking lot." What is left out of the definition you cite is that redevelopment almost always involves demolition of existing structures, or if not their total destruction and removal, some sort of death-blow, such as a large highway running through the center of a neighborhood.

"Your gift shop sentence would not be idiomatic." => Do you mean that it wouldn't be idiomatic for the same reason I mentioned in my OP, or for the fact that the gift shop might not have been demolished?

"redevelop" is not apt when a shop is converted into another kind of shop.   It is used when an entire neighborhood is razed or radically altered in order to build something new, a highway, say, or a casino, or a baseball stadium, or a prison. (Actual projects Philadelphia's Chinatown neighborhood has resisted, BTW.)  Other forms of redevelopment would include demoltion of a neighborhood of modest single-family row homes to build an upscale condo tower. The neighborhood increases in potential value and the taxes are dramatically increased, forcing the residents out.

"area" is too  vague.  If a large mall complex is built on 250 acres of farmland,  an "area" is involved but that is "development" not "redevelopment".  Redevelopment always involves ousting of a significant number of existing residents, either because their homes were taken or because the neighborhood becomes unlivable.

What about this case: there's a huge market being turned into an equally large housing complex.  Is the following sentence correct: "The market is redeveloped into a housing complex." I mean no residents live in the market, so no one is really ousted. Or what if it's not a market but a rice field, which is also equally large?

"It changed into a travel agent" or "became a travel agent" or "was replaced by a travel agent" would be better. How can you read a dictionary definition and then decide "Actually I'm going to use this to mean something else entirely"? If you don't trust the dictionary, you're not going to get far.

@StuartF That's because my teacher (he's a non-native, but he's on a higher level than I am) used it that way. Honestly, I've seen both my teacher and dictionary definitions being not (entirely) correct/clear before. That's why I'm here.

"The open-air market district has been redeveloped into a housing complex"  is possible.  I find  redeveloped into to be somewhat clumsy, but that's a stylistic issue.

Are these options better than "redeveloped into": transformed/turned/converted/changed + into? I feel that they can be used for both areas and buildings. I'm not sure though.

Redevelopment usually implies that some old or redundant or derelict building(s)  have been removed or refurbished and some, hopefully, bright new structure built in their place. For example, in London Covent Garden Market used to be the wholesale centre of fruit, vegetables and flowers in the city. When the market relocated further out, the site was redeveloped into boutique shops, restaurants and a museum.

We don't normally use "redevelop" when referring to a single building or shop. However, it can be used as a form of synecdoche -- using a word that describes a large thing for one part of it (or vice versa). If the area containing the gift shop was redeveloped, then the conversion of the shop into a travel agency was one part of that redevelopment.
Using this figure of speech allows the context of the conversion to be indicated all at once, rather than a more verbose

There used to be a gift shop here, but it became a travel agency during the redevelopment of the town.

